# GIST exclude constraint with a specific value

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way to represent a constraint, where I prevent date range overlaps, but only when a column equals a specific value? So I can have zero or many inactive, but only ever one active?

I'm running into a problem where i need a gist constraint to check date range overlaps but only if a column equals a specific value ('active' in this case).

We have a table which has dates and there can be overlap, if a column equals a specific value (active can only ever have one, but inactive can be zero or many).

GIST seems to be able to say prevent any duplicate (2 active, but also excludes 1 active, 1 inactive, or inactive > 1).

Putting this in two constraints fails, because the gist only covers the range overlap and join id.

e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE "a_table" 
  ADD CONSTRAINT "CHK_some_name" 
  EXCLUDE USING gist ("a_join_id" WITH =, tstzrange("start_time", "end_time") WITH &&)
```

```
ALTER TABLE "a_table" 
  ADD CONSTRAINT "CHK_some_name" 
  EXCLUDE USING gist ("an_enum" with =, "a_join_id" WITH =, tstzrange("start_time", "end_time") WITH &&)
```

Any help/insight would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need a partial constraint.

```
alter table a_table add constraint foobar exclude using gist 
    (tstzrange("start_time", "end_time") WITH &&) where (active);
```